# How to duplicate/clone a database in MongoDB with C#

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

At some events, I want to call a function, that should make a copy of the database and save it as a new MongoDB database with it's name as current Date time.

I just need the C# syntax to copy/duplicate/clone the mongodb database.